# How can I add product gallery images programmatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've made a Wordpress-Plugin that uploads an Image and lets me create a Woocommerce product using this.

I use the uploaded image to create the product and product image, which is already working, but I can't seem to find a way how I could add altered versions or different pictures as product-gallery images.

This is how I create the Thumbnail, this is already working. Now I also want to add product-gallery Images. How do I do this?

```
$attachment = array(

   'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],

   'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),

   'post_content'   => '',

   'post_status'    => 'inherit'

);

// Create the attachment

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $insert_id );

// Define attachment metadata

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

// Assign metadata to attachment
                    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data );

// And finally assign featured image to post

set_post_thumbnail( $insert_id, $attach_id );
```

Comment: Hope this answer resolves your query:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606707/6653215

Answer (score 1):

Setting product gallery images is also pretty simple, if you want to use WC_product class object to set gallery images then you can call it's function like below.

```
$objProduct = new WC_Product_Simple();
$galleryimage_ids = array();
// $galleryimage_ids is list of gallery images ids, existing 
//or you may insert post attachments to get the ids of images. 
$objProduct->set_gallery_image_ids( $galleryimage_ids );
$new_product_id = $objProduct->save();
```

Or by direct method you can insert gallery images for a product by directly updating post meta e.g below.

```
$media = get_attached_media('image', $pid); //get media attached to past post
update_post_meta($pid, '_product_image_gallery', implode(',', array_keys($media)));
```